# Why doesn't a real variable's conjugate evaluate to itself?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, complex, assumptions

I have this code (it's just a snippet to exemplify my issue):

```
Assuming[Element[a, Reals],Conjugate[a]]
```

Which results in the output:

```
Conjugate[a]
```

Which I find problematic, as the conjugation operation is clearly redundant here in light of the assumption *a* being real. Is there a way to make this evaluate to simply *a*?

Comment: `Assuming` only alters what `Simplify`, `Reduce` et al do. It doesn't affect ordinary evaluation.

Comment: `Refine` is more or less the basic "evaluate-with-assumptions" function. `In[240]:= Assuming[Element[a, Reals], Refine[Conjugate[a]]]

Out[240]= a`. More generally, only those functions that take an `Assumptions` argument will react also to an ambient `Assuming` block. `Refine` is such a function, whereas `Conjugate` is not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `Conjugate[a]` gives the complex conjugate of the complex number `a`

```
Assuming[Element[a, Reals], Conjugate[a]] // ComplexExpand
```

> a

Or

```
Conjugate[a] // Conjugate
```

> a

Or

```
 Conjugate[a + 0 I] // Conjugate
```

> a

Comment: wow, the latter two confuses me slightly

Comment: Read `Conjugate[a]` as `Conjugate[a + 0 I]` and it becomes clearer

Comment: The latter two are simply `Conjugate[Conjugate[a]]` which of course is just `a`